# How to Remote Control Google Doc Presentation?

Tags: bluetooth, remote-control, google-drive

I want to remote control Google Doc Presentations. Is there an app for this?

Bonus point if it can connect via Bluetooth to my Linux-based PC.

Comment: For those who came to this post as they knew support was built-in a long time ago, allowing for controlling using a mobile browser, that's no longer true: [What happened to the "View Together" option?](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/hXPo8hWTrlU/80UcDQ7YwvgJ). Sad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply use a bluetooth/wifi mouse app like [PRemoteDroid](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.pierre.remotedroid.client). There are [a bunch of others](https://market.android.com/search?q=bluetooth%20mouse&c=apps), and generally speaking they just allow your device to be used as a mouse/keyboard input. If you can pair with your PC it should work, although I've never tried it myself (I do use PRemoteDroid to pair with and remotely control my Xoom, though; works great).

Another option would be some kind of [VNC or remote desktop client](https://market.android.com/search?q=vnc%20client&c=apps), but that's not as lightweight and some of them don't support Linux (Splashtop, for example, doesn't have a Linux server, IIRC).

Answer (score 4):

[Google Presentation Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vorticontech.presentationremote) is great and really easy to use on your Android phone. It is dependent on the Chrome Extension "Google Presentation Remote".

Comment: Link doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I'm the developer of an app called [WatchPresenter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zuluindia.watchpresenter), which lets you control Google Slides from your phone. It doesn't require phone and computer to be on the same network (as long as both have Internet it will work).

You control the slides by using the volume buttons, so you can switch the phone's screen off (easier to handle without hving to look at the phone, and less risk of unintentional clicks).

Additionally, if you have a Android Wear device, it lets you control the presentation with wrist gestures.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far to mark it spam – if you include a full disclosure with your post. References: [How do I mention my own products in answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15787/192154) / [What is the correct way to add your own product to an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142907/192154) / [Limits for self-promotion in answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57497/192154)

Comment: It works thx! But fix bug with multiple clicks per second :)

Comment: @DawidDrozd can you give me more details about the bug so that I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I did end up using the paid app [Presenter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ratisbonsoft.presenter.full). I liked the interface and the way it dominantly shows the presentation time.